# Adding timepoints to a multirow dataframe based on ID and date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As the title says it, my dataframe looks as follows:

| ID | Follow up month | Value-x | value -y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 12 | 12 |
| 1 | 0 | 11 | 14 |
| 2 | 0 | 10 | 11 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 12 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 13 | 12 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 | 5 |

I want to add another column called timepoint which would make the table look like as follows:

| ID | Follow up month | Value-x | value -y | Timepoint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 12 | 12 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 11 | 14 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 10 | 11 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 13 | 12 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 13 | 12 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 | 5 | 2 |

So far I tried to group the rows by their ID and follow up month and then apply a timepoint using cumcount. This didn't give me any results any help on how to handle this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to decide if timepoint is 1 or 2? and can it be more than 2? now, it looks like when follow up month is 0, then timepoint is 1 and when follow up month is 3 then timepoint is 2. I assume you want something different

Comment: I decide that based on the follow up month per ID, so each ID had 4 follow up moments( month 0, month 3, month 6 and month 12). However I will be removing certain follow up months if some values are missing so it will always just be up to two timepoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your table I can only infer that you want to create the `Timepoint` column based on the corresponding values in `Follow up month`, which will look like:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
wt = StringIO("""ID  Follow up month  Value-x  value -y
1  0  12  12
1  0  11  14
2  0  10  11
2  3  11  0
2  0  12  1
1  3  13  12
2  3  11  5""")

df = pd.read_csv(wt, sep='\s\s+')
df['Timepoint'] = df['Follow up month'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x==0 else 2)
df
```

Output:

```
   ID  Follow up month  Value-x  value -y  Timepoint
0   1                0       12        12          1
1   1                0       11        14          1
2   2                0       10        11          1
3   2                3       11         0          2
4   2                0       12         1          1
5   1                3       13        12          2
6   2                3       11         5          2
```

##### Edit

Based on your comment, this should be what you want:

```
def timepoint(s):
    if not s.isin([0]).any() and s.iloc[0] == 3:
        return 1
    else:
        return s.apply(lambda x: 1 if x==0 else 2)

df['Timepoint'] = df.groupby('ID')['Follow up month'].transform(timepoint)
```

Comment: yes this would work, I was maybe to hastened with posting the question. Sometimes there is no Follow up month 0 and I have data starting at follow up month 3 so that would be the timepoint 1 for that ID

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment. Do let me know if it  is still not the desired outcome.